# Suggested Protein/Fat/Carb Ratio?

Tags: nutrition

I'm 5'9", 158.  Plan on shedding 10 pounds of fat and gaining muscle.  I hope to get into amazing shape.  (I'm already in shape, but I'm aiming for getting cut!)

I'm curious what I should aim for in terms of my Protein/Fat/Carb ratio?

I generally eat around 1,500 calories per day.

Comment: are you a woman or a man? 1,500 is nothing for a guy.

Comment: @siouxfan Weight loss questions unrelated to sport and fitness are off-topic.

Comment: @MikeS How many calories daily would you recommend for the situation? I find it hard to eat more than 1500 calories in a day. Maybe that is why I am not seeing many results!

Comment: pump up that protein intake like the world's about to end, decrease you carbohydrate intake to a minimum and increase you omega-3s (think oils and butter and nuts) and omega-6s fats (think fish).

Comment: Shedding fat and gaining muscle are contradictory goals.  This is why a lot of bodybuilders go through build/cut cycles as opposed to trying to do it all at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to consult a sports nutritionist.  There are FAR too many variables that affect your metabolism and how you digest food to tell you what you need.

That being said, you can take a few things into consideration.

**1) You have to consume calories if you want to lose weight.**
     -If your body is needing 2,500 CAL/day, and you are only consuming 1,500 your body will think you are starving.  This does not mean eat a 2,000 CAL burger, you still have to be responsible with your calorie consumption.

**2) Carbohydrates are needed to burn fat.**
     -Therefore, you CAN NOT burn fat without carbohydrates in your diet.  You will lose fat size; but, you will not actually burn the fat.  Mike S. is correct about the varying degrees at which people burn carbohydrates. This is one of the reasons you need to consult a sports nutritionist.

**3) After a certain point, protein consumption becomes inefficient and you pee out excess.**
     -This level is different for everyone and is another reason you need to consult a professional.  The United States Registered Dietitian's Association states that it, "recommends 0.8 grams of protein per kilogram of ideal body weight per day."  A sub-point to be made here is that natural sources of protein are more beneficial that supplements.  The exception to that rule is when you can not consume enough protein by eating regular foods and need a supplement.

Comment: John P.  Thanks for the referral to wikipedia of fitness sites.  Here is a link to a peer reviewed article that states, "The inability to consume enough calories to meet energy requirements is a common threat to survival. To meet this danger, animals retard their fuel depletion by lowering their metabolic rate..." http://www.nejm.org/doi/pdf/10.1056/NEJM199706193362507         My second is not misleading.  There are very few ways the body can burn fat without consuming carbs. One is your body breaks down muscle (not ideal). Your insulin response theory is correct if you were to eat carbs only.

Comment: I give up. Nutritional science is poorly understood at best. Since I can't find the military study any more, I withdraw my statement.

Comment: I believe that the 'maximum quotas' of protein we all hear about refer to the amount that the body can assimilate into tissue. Your body can manufacture glucose from excess protein for general energy as well. The protein quota ideology comes from the carbohydrate centric food pyramid era. Excellent advice though.

Comment: I'm interested to hear more about the shrinking fat cells vs the burning of them. I had no idea there was a difference?

Comment: Fat cells don't go away. They are basically big bags where fat gets stored. When you have a lot of excess fat storage, the cells are big. When you lose that fat storage, they get small, but you don't "burn" the cells themselves, you use the fat in them for fuel. I also encourage you to read on the "starvation mode" myth and how fat actually gets used. Grohlier's first two points are either fallacies or only partially correct.

Answer (score 2):

Most diets that are followed before competition by body-builders are low-carb ones. [Why We Get Fat: And What to Do About It](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0307272702) also strongly advocates keeping carbs to absolute minimum.

You need protein to keep your muscles grow. The most your body can process 2.2g to 2.5g per kilogram, which in your case amounts to 173g of protein. Which is roughly 46% of your 1500 calories/day.

What I suggest is
10% Carbs
45% Fat
45% Protein

I follow this very same diet, and the results are quite satisfying.

Comment: where does the remaining 10% come from ;)

Comment: Good catch, fixed :)

Comment: Low carb diets have been proven to be harmful. Suggesting one is irresponsible.

Comment: @RobinAshe Proven by whom? Please give a source.

Comment: Wow people still believe that low carb is harmful in 2012? People confuse lowER (in comparison to the carb rich diets of our largely overweight populations today) with the ketone diet (zero carb). There IS debate over the long term effects of a zero carb diet (using ketones as opposed to glucose as the primary fuel source) but not much at all over the efficacy and benefits of a lowER carb diet.

Comment: 10% carbs is incredibly low. That's not like suggesting 25% carbs. 

Fung et al, Annals of Internal Medicine, Issue 153(5) is your source.

Comment: @RobinAshe The "Low" carb % in the study is 40%. It's also an epidemiological study based on food journals, which is useful, but not really proof of anything.

Comment: The problem with low carb diets is they often lead to fatigue, diziness, etc.  As is the case with myself.

Low carb diets take away a main energy source for your body and often focus on protein, which in excess can lead to kidney problems.

Comment: @siouxfan45 Changing energy sources from carbs to fat, or fat to carb, can be difficult for the the body (it is sometimes referred to as Atkins Flu). Although it only lasts for about 10 days for most people, it can be ameliorated by keeping your salt and fat intake up. After the body has adjusted, it can run on fat better than it does on carbs. I think your claims regarding kidneys are unsubstantiated for people without renal disease, but the diet is referred to as LCHF (low carb- high fat), not LCHP (high protein).

Comment: @Michael the diet boris suggests is both high protein and high fat

Comment: I wouldn't call it necessarily 'high protein'. In this case the % are high because the total calorie intake is low. So a 2.2g * X kg = high percentage, but the total amount is consistent with what athletes take when building muscle.

Comment: +1 for the advice. at 1500 cal the 45%/173g protein is reasonable. but under any kind of exercise the total cal need will increase quickly. recommend carbs to stay at 10%, protein to stay at 2.5g/kg which will make it drop as a percent, when total increase. the balance should then be more and more fat to fuel your energy needs while staying lean.

Comment: If you're saying it's not high protein due to the overall amount being eaten, then it's incredibly low carb, and that isn't going to work at all.

Comment: 'that isn't going to work at all'... how did you come to that conclusion? Low-carb diets are the most effective for weight loss, according to lots of research (already gave a link to one). Also this very same diet is what I used to both gain muscle and get abs to show for the first time in my life.

Answer (score 0):

Some people can burn carbohydrates more efficiently than others. I'm currently on 50,30,20 (pfc) and I've had good results. I'd definitely try lower carb first as that has the best success rate. If you have trouble putting on muscle I'd add in more calories 200 at a time.

Your appetite can be directly linked to your metabolism and so that would be my guess as to why you don't feel like eating any more than you are. The best way to increase your metabolism is to eat more and more often (ironically), which will in turn increase your appetite.

Here is a diet plan which equates to about 2800 calories (50,30,20) (protein,fat,carb).

```
Meal 1: 4 eggs + 1 piece of toast + 40g protein shake
Meal 2: 230g meat + 200g vegies + 50g rice
Meal 3: 25g almonds + 40g protein shake
Meal 4: 230g meat + 200g vegies + 50g rice
Meal 5: 25g almonds + 40g protein shake
Meal 6: 230g meat + 200g vegies + 25g + almonds (no rice)
```

Add to that a quality fish oil, a multivitamin, and probiotics for digestive health. All weights are uncooked and 'meat' refers to anything lean (chicken breast skinless, lean beef mince, tuna, etc). Veggies excludes potatoes - just stick to green fibrous like broccoli. Protein powder must be low carb as possible (no sugar). Drink plenty of water (at least 3.5 litres) but not on top of a stomach full of food!

Remember, its mostly about FOOD. As well as all this, you should be training about 3 or 4 times a week and HARD. Train every set to failure. Record your reps/weights and ensure you are always adding reps or weights (ever increasing intensity). There is a lot more to it all but this will be a good start. 15-20 reps on the compounds like squats and deadlifts will burn the most fat whilst growing (or at least maintaining) muscle. Forget cardio - and forget situps.

It sounds like you already have a grasp on listening to your body. At first you will feel like you are forcing food in and intuitively you will feel like you are eating too much. This will quickly change as your metabolism gets up a gear. You will enjoy sustained energy levels throughout the day.

Good luck.

Comment: What's your source on blood type influencing digestion?

Comment: Its a personal hypothesis that is entirely unproven - much like your 1:1:1 theory. I've removed it.

Comment: Actually, 1:1:1 is pretty close to a number of diets that have shown the best results for consistent health benefits.

Comment: @RobinAshe provide sources for your claims? Because diets like Atkins, Paleo etc. based on low-carb are overwhelmingly beating all the others. If you want a reference, a Stanford study here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eREuZEdMAVo

Comment: Atkins is a heart attack factory.

Comment: @siouxfan45 Please skip the unsubstantiated and inflammatory claims. You aren't adding to the discussion.

Comment: siouxfan45, actually Atkin's diet is the oldest, still very popular diet (originally introduced in the 70s).

Comment: Yes, and to add to that, there are more and more cardiologists that are starting to realize the dangers of a high carb percentage diet, and taking a close look at Atkins style diets.

Comment: The journal articles have been showing that while high protein diet people lose pretty much the same as someone on a low calorie diet, their body composition improved significantly. This is the key to the success of the high protein diet. You keep most of your metabolism pumping/fat burning muscle. Calorie deficient diets lose equal amounts of each. You end up a skinny/fat person with a terrible metabolism on traditional diets.

Comment: @JohnP your exactly right. People are starting to find the link between exccesive glucose in your diet (from carbs) and inflammatory based illnesses like heart disease and high cholesterol. Saturated fat actually helps to LOWER cholesterol. Whenever I hear people talk about the virtues of high carbs and low fat I just have a hand to head moment. Stuck in the dark ages.

Answer (score -3):

1:1:1, or 33% to 33% to 33%, or anything else to that effect, however you want to look at it. You probably won't nail it exactly, but the most important thing is to get a good balance of all the macronutrients, so your body can decide how to use what it needs.

A good rule of thumb I go by is to make sure I've had *at least* one of each throughout the day, and *at least* 3 different sources of protein, carb and fat each throughout the week. Then you won't be seriously deficient in anything, even if you're not particularly balanced.

Comment: -1 for totally ignorant and misleading advice. 1:1:1 is not how people naturally eat, is not consistent with any good diet, is not the way athletes eat. Having enough of the essential nutrients in your diet is what a 'balanced diet' means.

Comment: Not at all, all the macronutrients are essential, which means you need a good amount of all 3. The low carb diet you suggested has been proven to be harmful. Nobody's ever gotten sick from a 1:1:1 diet.

Comment: @RobinAshe What is essential in carbohydrate? How do you know no one has ever gotten sick from 1:1:1?

Comment: 1:1:1 isn't extreme in anyway, it doesn't lead to any nutritional deficiency. People who don't eat much carbohydrates end up fatiguing much quicker, making it particularly essential for people in athletic endeavours.

Comment: Why would they fatigue quicker? Carbs get converted to ATP much faster than proteins and fats, but once in the blood, the energy from all the sources works the same way.

Comment: Very high metabolic exercise uses glycogen very quickly. (For example, Fran in crossfit.) If that exercise is extended for several minutes, glycogen will be used faster than it can be replenished, and an individual eating very low carbohydrate might run out, and "bonk". (This has happened to me.) But this type of exercise is not required for anyone, and most people don't do it.

Comment: If you are truly "bonking" to where the brain is shutting off motor function (See Gabrielle Scheiss, Sian Welch/Wendy Ingraham), then you are way too deficient in carbs. Your liver should have ~ 1400 kcals of glycogen stored, and your muscles in the neighborhood of 10g/kg of lean body weight. That should sustain you for far longer than several minutes. Either you are just tired and not actually bonking, or you are starting in a dangerously depleted state.

Comment: @JohnP Bonking isn't exactly a technical term; I'm using it to describe a very clear and unexpected drop-off in performance. Try not eating any non green vegetable carbohydrates for a week. You will feel completely fine, you will be able to run distances. Everything will be great. Then try a 5-10 minute crossfit workout; it won't go well. There is nothing dangerous about that state, you just run out of energy for that type of activity. I can't speak to the very specific amounts of glycogen you are listing, but I can speak to the result.

Comment: "Bonking" as you refer to it only happened with me when I was on a low carb program WHILST eating insufficient calories. I now eat my 3000 (50% protein) and I have never felt better energy wise. I don't even need pre-workout drinks or anything before I train.

Comment: The OP would be eating a low amount of calories, so that would very much be a problem.